# Persistent PowerShell job

Tags: powershell, jobs

Is it possible to launch a PowerShell Job that persists after the creating script terminates? So far as I can tell, the Job is tied to the initiating script.

What I have now is this

```
$name = 'iexplore'
$waitTimeinMinutes = 30

Start-Job -argumentList @($name, $waitTimeinMinutes) -scriptblock {
    param (
        [string]$name,
        [int]$waitTimeinMinutes
    )

    $cutoff = [DateTime]::Now.AddMinutes($waitTimeinMinutes)

    while ([DateTime]::Now -lt $cutoff) {
        if (Get-Process -name:$name -errorAction:silentlyContinue) {
            Stop-Process -name:$name -force -errorAction:silentlyContinue
        }
        if (Get-Service $name -errorAction:silentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.status -eq "running"}) {
            Stop-Service $name -force -errorAction:silentlyContinue
        }

        Start-Sleep -s:10
    }
}
```

It works as intend. For half an hour it watches for a Process or Service called iexplore and kills it if it is found. However, I need to continue processing a calling script, and this job is killed when the calling script terminates. I presume there must be a way to initiate a job separate from the calling script?

Comment: This sounds like a XY problem. Why are you killing IE? Are you trying to prevent web browsing? Is there a test that gets stuck? Something else?

Comment: The (first) use case is a very odd installer, which will start a process as part of the install, but will not complete while that process is running. So I want to start a job that will kill the process once it starts, then launch the installer, which will be able to complete once the job does it's thing, and continue on with the next install. IE is just being used for the proof of concept, but I have also seen installers that launch a web page and won't complete, so I could see it being used that way too.

Comment: I should also mention, this is a bit of a hack. Ultimately I will add the job creation to the main script, which will not terminate until all the installs are done, so the job won't get killed. But in the meantime, I want to use a feature of my existing code to run an external PS1 which initiates the job then completes and returns control to the main script. And therein lies the problem, if the script called by the main script can't complete and leave the job running, then the install can't be started. But if it does complete, the job dies and the install stalls.